# PDE - bounded solution

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in\mathcal{C}^2(\Omega)\cap\mathcal{C}^0(\overline{\Omega})$ be a classical solution of $\Delta u=u^3-u$ on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Then it holds that $|u|\leq 1$ on $\Omega$.
Does someone know how to prove that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what should be the range of $u$ satisfying following equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172747/what-should-be-the-range-of-u-satisfying-following-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Call $\Omega_1=\{ x\in \Omega : u(x)>1\}$. Then $\Delta u >0$ in $\Omega_1$ and therefore, by the maximum principle, $u\leq 1$ in $\Omega_1$ (since $u$ is either $0$ or $1$ on $\partial \Omega_1$), therefore $\Omega_1=\emptyset$

Comment: Thanks! But why is $\Omega_1$ path-connected? This is needed for the maximum principle that I know.

Comment: Apply this argument to each connected component. No need to assume that $\Omega_1$ is path connected.