# Bound of the solution of nonlinear PDE $\,\Delta u = u^3 - u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, elliptic-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I am trying to solve the following nonlinear PDE problem.

> Let $D$ be a bounded simply-connected domain on $\mathbb R^2$ and $u(x,y)$ be a classical solution of the nonliner elliptic problem:
>
> $$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
> \Delta u &= u^3 - u & \text{ in } D \\
> u &= 0 & \text{ on } \partial D
> \end{aligned}\right.$$
>
> Show that $-1\le u(x,y) \le 1$ in $D$.
>   Can $u(x,y) = \pm 1$ be achieved in $D$?

Since the equation is nonlinear, we cannot apply maximum principle directly.
The only idea coming to my mind is to incapsulate points in $D$ where $u>1$ into closed curve, and to try to justify max principle for subharmonic functions within the curve-bounded portion of the domain.
However I could not complete solution following this approach.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what should be the range of $u$ satisfying following equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172747/what-should-be-the-range-of-u-satisfying-following-equation)

Answer (score 5):

You can use similar techniques to those used to prove the maximum principle. For example, suppose that $u > 1$ at any point in $D$. Then $\max_{\overline D} u > 1$. This maximum must be achieved in the interior of $D$ since $u=0$ on the boundary. At the point $x_0$ where the maximum is achieved, we have $$\Delta u(x_0) \le 0.$$ On the other hand, since $u(x_0) > 1$, we have $u(x_0)^3 - u(x_0) > 0$. Thus we have $$\Delta u(x_0)\le 0  <  u(x_0)^3 - u(x_0);$$ a contradiction. Hence $u \le 1$ in $D$.

Likewise, if $u < -1$ at some point in $D$, then $\text{min}_{\overline D} u < -1$.  At the point $x_1$ where the minimum is achived (which again, is in the interior), we have $$\Delta u(x_1) \ge 0 > u(x_1)^3 - u(x_1)$$ which is a contradiction. Hence $u \ge -1$. This shows that $-1 \le u \le 1$ in $D$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about the last question though? (Can $u(x,y) = \pm 1$ be achieved in $D$?)

Comment: @Vlad For the last question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1455179/70305).