# Semi-linear PDE Maximum Principle

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar{\Omega})$  be a solution of $\Delta u=u^3-u$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on $\delta \Omega$.  Choose a suitable test function to prove that $u(x) \in [-1,1]$ for all $x \in \Omega$.

I am really lost how to choose a test function that will help me show my claim.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A quick guess is $v(x) = \max(u(x)-1,0)$ (or a smoothed version of it).

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Once I decide on a suitable test function, any ideas how I need to implement it to show that $u(x) \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: Typically, you would use $u(x) \, v(x) = v^2(x)$ and, similarly, $\nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v(x) = \|\nabla v(x)\|^2$ ($\nabla$ is the weak derivative). Finally, you end up with something like $\int \|\nabla v\|^2 + v^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \le 0$, which shows $v = 0$, hence, $u \le 1$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the line of logic.  Where did you get $u(x)v(x)=v^2(x)$ and $\nabla u(x)\nabla v(x) = || \nabla v(x) ||^2$ and choose to integrate the sum?

Comment: The first was indeed wrong, it should read $u(x) \, v(x) = (v(x) + 1) \, v(x)$, just by a distinction of cases. The second one follows since $\nabla v = \chi_{\{u > 1\}} \, \nabla u$ with the characteristic set of $\{x:u(x)>1\}$. Finally, the integral appears after testing the PDE with $v$ and integration by parts.

Comment: What exactly gets integrated by parts?

Comment: $\int v \, \Delta u = -\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$...

Comment: Okay I guess I'm confused on when I test the PDE with v.  Am I supposed to be substituting  $u(x)=v(x)+1$ into $\Delta u = u^3-u$?  I guess I'm just lost how I get from the substitution to the final claim.  Finally does showing $u \leq 0$ really imply that $u \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: I will post an answer...

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172747/70305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set $v(x) = \max(u(x)-1,0)$. Then, $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Moreover, we have $\nabla v(x) = \chi_{\{x:u(x)>1\}}(x) \, \nabla u(x)$.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
u(x) \, v(x) &= (v(x) + 1) \, v(x) \\
u(x)^3 \, v(x) &= (v(x) + 1)^3 \, v(x) \\
\nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v(x) &= \|\nabla v(x)\|^2
\end{align*}
Now, we multiply our pde pointwise with $v$ and integrate. This gives
$$0 = \int_\Omega (-\Delta u + u^3 - u ) \, v \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Since $v$ has zero boundary values, we can use integration by parts and obtain
$$0 = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + (u^3 - u ) \, v \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Now, we apply the above relations for the products between $u$ and $v$ and get
$$0 = \int_\Omega \|\nabla v\|^2 + ((v+1)^3 - (v+1) ) \, v \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Some simple calculations lead to
$$0 = \int_\Omega \|\nabla v\|^2 + v^4 + 3 \, v^3 + 2 \, v^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Since $v \ge 0$ we obtain
$$0 = \int_\Omega \|\nabla v\|^2 + v^4 + 3 \, v^3 + 2 \, v^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
\ge \int_\Omega \|\nabla v\|^2 + v^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Hence $v \equiv 0$, which yields $u \le 1$.

I would guess, $u \ge -1$ can be shown analogously.